# Automatically redirect logged in users nodejs passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Currently using node.js, express & passport.js to create a custom website/application.

Having followed several guides, I have a functioning login/logout system with authentication. However, should a user revisit and their session is still active, it doesn't redirect them to the 'dashboard'.

Current root route:

```
   /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/',function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });
```

I am making use of the `isAuthenticated` function, as below:

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

How do I get it to automatically redirect users with an existing session? Any pointers most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. In the / route, I queried whether `req.user` was set.

```
/* GET login page. */
router.get('/',function(req, res) {
    if(req.user){
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }else{
    // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
    res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a middleware with "/" endpoint something like this.

```
router.get('/', sessionValidate, function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('login');
});
```

Where sessionValidate looks something like this :

```
function sessionValidate(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.user,"i am here");
  users.findById(req.user,function(err, user) {
    if(user!=null){
      req.session.user = user;
      res.locals.user=user;
      res.redirect("/home")
    }
    else {
          next();
    }
  });
}
```